# Selenium WebDriver doesn't start on IIS 10, but works fine if app is hosted InProcess

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an `ASP.NET MVC CORE 3.0` app, my requirement is to run `Selenium` on `IIS 10`. When I host my app `InProcess` it works, as soon as I switch to `IIS` it stops working (without any error message and regardless of app pool profile). I have the following code, but I believe that the code is irrelevant to this particular issue.

```
public void OpenOrReuseDriver(bool headlessMode = false, bool reuse = true)
{
    if (!_driver.IsClosed()) return;
    if (reuse && _drivers.Any() && _drivers.Last().IsOpen())
        _driver = _drivers.Last();
    else
    {
        var chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}"); // Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() // AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory // Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\wwwroot
        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
        {
            BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
        };
        if (headlessMode)
        {
            chromeOptions.AddArguments(new List<string>
            {
                "--silent-launch",
                "--no-startup-window",
                "no-sandbox",
                "headless"
            });
            chromeService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        }

        _driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, chromeOptions);
        var size = new Size(1240, 720);
        _driver.Manage().Window.Size = size;
        _driver.Manage().Window.Position = PointUtils.CenteredWindowTopLeft(size).ToDrawingPoint();
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        _drivers.Add(_driver);
    }
}
```

I would like to know the steps that will make `Selenium` work with `IIS`.

Comment: *it works, as soon as I switch to `IIS` it stops working* an error message might be helpful. but i suspect it was due to the fact IIS application pool is ran under restricted user profile, while standalone will run using the current user profile.

Comment: There is no error message and it happens regardless of profile.

Comment: guess you need to hook a debugger and see why it broke...

Comment: There is no error from Selenium itself, no permission problem, debugging session is completely clear of exceptions as well. I wouldn't post if it wasn't the case.

Comment: I have similar problem using IIS and still struggling how to achieve this